# Сумма по условию Python

Tags: python

Есть списки с данными

- MAS = [1050, 2000, 2050, 2200] 1..k
- X = [2, 0, 6, 10, 1] 1..n
- сombs = [[1050, 2050], [2050, 2200], [1050, 1050, 2000], [1050, 1050,
  2050], [1050, 1050, 1050, 1050]] 1..n, 1..j

Не получается создать такой же размерностью список как и "MAS", в котором нужно Х умножить на количество сколько раз встречается в каждом наборе 1050 и просуммировать и так по каждому числу из списка MAS.

Пример:

- MAS[1] = 1050
- X[1] = 2
- в списке combs[1] есть число 1050 и встречается 1 раз
- значит 2*1+...+...

Comment: `[sum([X[index] * comb.count(value) for (index, comb) in enumerate(сombs)]) for value in MAS]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[sum([x * comb.count(mas) for x, comb in zip(X, combs)]) for mas in MAS]
```